# AWK script unexpected character

Tags: awk

I wrote this AWK script and get

```
awk: 2: unexpected character '''
awk: 2: unexpected character '''
```

I'm not sure what is going on.

Here is my code 
The file is named chan_wrd and chmod u+rx was used

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
'{gsub(/\<i\>/, "I");gsub(/\<awk\>/, "AWK");print}'
```

Comment: Because you have `'` at the beginning and end of line.

Comment: not sure why the code showed that way but the code is                #!/usr/bin/awk -f
'{gsub(/\<i\>/, "I");gsub(/\<awk\>/, "AWK");print}'

Comment: you're mixing up how to write awk on the command line ( `awk ' ...code... '` )  and how to write it in a script (see cbuckley's answer for an example). the `#!/...../awk -f` alone on the first line is called a "shebang". It is a way in Unix/linux to force a script to be executed by "/....../awk -f" instead of by the calling shell. That shebang will force the OS to execute: `/...../awk -f "name_of_the_calling_script"`, and that awk will then execute the other lines (as they are not commented out by a "#")

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the quotes in a script itself — you only need them when passing the script as a command-line argument to `awk`. Your script should be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
{
    gsub(/\<i\>/, "I");
    gsub(/\<awk\>/, "AWK");
    print
}
```

Comment: I think he's using `\<` and `\>` as word delimiters. That's part of GNU awk, not sure if any other awks support it.

Comment: Aha; I wasn't aware of those delimiters — I've only used `\y`.